# Bind List of Complex Object to Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding

I have a model with ID, Area, Debug, Error, Info, Warning, Fatal properties and I want to bind a list of this object with model binder in MVC.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="[@i].ID" value="@Model.ElementAt(i).ID"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="[@i].Area" value="@Model.ElementAt(i).Area" />
                @Model.ElementAt(i).Area
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="[@i].Debug" type="checkbox" id="[@i].Debug" class="regular-checkbox" @(Model.ElementAt(i).Debug ? "checked='checked'" : "") value="@Model.ElementAt(i).Debug"/><label  for="[@i].Debug" ></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="[@i].Error" type="checkbox" id="[@i].Error" class="regular-checkbox" @(Model.ElementAt(i).Error ? "checked='checked'" : "") value="@Model.ElementAt(i).Error"/><label for="[@i].Error" ></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="[@i].Info" type="checkbox" id="[@i].Info" class="regular-checkbox" @(Model.ElementAt(i).Info ? "checked='checked'" : "") value="@Model.ElementAt(i).Info"/><label for="[@i].Info" ></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="[@i].Warnning" type="checkbox" id="[@i].Warnning" class="regular-checkbox" @(Model.ElementAt(i).Warnning ? "checked='checked'" : "") value="@Model.ElementAt(i).Warnning"/><label for="[@i].Warnning" ></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="[@i].Fatal" type="checkbox" id="[@i].Fatal" class="regular-checkbox" @(Model.ElementAt(i).Fatal ? "checked='checked'" : "") value="@Model.ElementAt(i).Fatal"/><label for="[@i].Fatal" ></label>
            </td>

        </tr>
    }
```

and also I have an action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditAll(IList<LogSetting> logsettings)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var logsetting in logsettings)
            {
                db.LogSettings.Attach(logsetting);
                db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(logsetting, EntityState.Modified);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

       return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

the problem is when I uncheck a checkbox for a row and submit the form the value of corresponding row become false, but then if I check this checkbox and submit the form it does not come to true, and in this case when I set a breakpoint on save action I see the value is stil false.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: when you set a breakpoint in your action, do you get a list with the expected number of rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this relates to your issue, but I had a similar result. When I posted a form with a checkbox checked *and disabled*, the posted value would get set to false. Removing the `"disabled"` attribute before posting solved the problem.